# Limit of quotient of power series

Tags: limits, analysis, power-series

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}$
with $a_{n},b_{n}\geq0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be two power
series with radius of convergence 1. Assume that the limit
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\nearrow1}\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}}
\end{eqnarray}
exists. Morally this means that in a certain sense the sequence $(a_n)$ grows slower than $(b_n)$. Is it possible
to make this statement precise, e.g. by deducing statements about
the asymptotic behaviour of $a_{n}/b_{n}$?

Comment: You are expected to share your work on the problem. What have you tried?

Comment: We have $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n+1}} = 1$, but the sequence $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is $\frac{1}{0},0,\frac{1}{0},0,\cdots$